# Will Spark SQL always check all partitions' information even appoint partition?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I execute SQL query with specific partition:

```
spark-sql --conf spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=true \
 -e "select * from default.s_shouq_user where dt='2018-10-17' limit 10"
```

and I get the exception like this (`dt=2015-12-22 is` the first partition of the table):

```
Java.io.IOException: Malformed ORC file hdfs://jilian/hai/bo/dw/default.db/s_shouq_user/dt=2015-12-22/000005_0. Invalid postscript.
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl.ensureOrcFooter(ReaderImpl.java:250)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl.extractMetaInfoFromFooter(ReaderImpl.java:
```

Comment: I use spark2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

This issue has fixed in v2.3.1